# GoJs get node key used link

Tags: gojs

Gojs if click on the link, want to find out the keys of both nodes that are connected.

When I select a link in a diagram using the ones I create,
I want to get information that the link is connected to which node starting from which node.

I can find the information want from the node, but I want to know the information through the link that the user chose when he selected the link.

[image]

How can I do get the nodes key?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to get selected Links

```
myDiagram.selection.each(function(part) {
    if (part instanceof go.Link) {
        console.log("link", part.data);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, if you're creating the links using template, the selection handlers can be added directly while creating the template.

For example, to add a selection handler to this basic link template

```
 diagram.linkTemplate =
  $(go.Link,
    $(go.Shape),
    $(go.Shape,
    { toArrow: "OpenTriangle", fill: null })
  );
```

add `{selectionChanged: handler}` to the template

```
 diagram.linkTemplate =
  $(go.Link,
    {
      selectionChanged: onSelectionChanged, // your handler here
    },
    $(go.Shape),
    $(go.Shape,
    { toArrow: "OpenTriangle", fill: null })
  );
```

And in the handler you can get the node details like below,

```
function onSelectionChanged(link){
  if (link instanceof go.Link) {
    const { fromNode, toNode } = link;
    console.log(fromNode.key);
    console.log(toNode.key);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
theLink.fromNode.key
theLink.toNode.key
```

Comment: There was no URL link in my answer -- there was only the answer to the question and it was even in JavaScript code.

Comment: Got it. The comment was auto posted.

Comment: "auto posted".  Why?  That was counter-productive, wasting both the questioner's time and my time.

Comment: This came up when it falls under the review section of stackoverflow, since the answer had very less content with no explanation. Except the two lines of code even if it's correct, it doesn't explains what it's meant to do.

Comment: @Shane, If my answer satisfied your question, please accept it as an official answer.  Otherwise I can elaborate on it.